# Get column value length, not column max length of value

Tags: oracle, string-length

How do I get actual length of value in column?

My (oracle) sql command returns maximum length of value that can be inserted in the column instead of real length of value.

How to fix this?

```
SQL> SELECT typ, length(t1.typ)
     FROM AUTA_VIEW t1;

TYP        LENGTH(T1.TYP)
---------- --------------
BMW                    10
BMW                    10
BMW                    10
Ferrari                10
BMW                    10
Audi                   10
Audi                   10
Audi                   10
Ferrari                10
Ferrari                10
Mercedes               10
```

Comment: Is your column TYP a CHAR datatype? CHAR is a fixed length.
If it is a VARCHAR2 your query should work.

Comment: @oraNob Good catch - in any case, the trim() approach also works when using CHAR.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`LENGTH()` does return the string length (just verified). I suppose that your data is padded with blanks - try

```
SELECT typ, LENGTH(TRIM(t1.typ))
FROM AUTA_VIEW t1;
```

instead.

As `OraNob` mentioned, another cause could be that `CHAR` is used in which case `LENGTH()` would also return the column width, not the string length. However, the `TRIM()` approach also works in this case.