# SQL: updating a column value by conditioning on other value's length from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

lets say I have table Book
and columns are: color and name,

I want to update book's color to orange if name of that book is more than 5 characters long..of course update of every book in table like that...so any ideas ?sorry for bad English.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have provided a good explanation of the problem. However, you should also show your attempt at solving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get column value length, not column max length of value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064621/get-column-value-length-not-column-max-length-of-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update Book
    Set Color = 'Orange'
    Where Length(name) > 5
```

Comment: The string literal delimiter in Oracle is single-quote, not double-quote.

Answer (score 1):

```
update book set color = 'ORANGE' where length(name) > 5;
```

VKP is right, you should always show what you have tried. Here is your answer to your homework.